# How to check the version of Spark Core, not pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a different version of pyspark and spark core (what's installed in the cluster), is there a way to print the version of spark core? everything so far gives me the version of pyspark. I have tried the following from the user machines:

```
pyspark.__version__

ss.version  # same as spark.version

sc.version

./bin/spark-submit --version
```

EDIT:

In case this helps, I am running Spark on a Yarn cluster which has access to multiple machines (not on K8S) and accessing them via pyspark from user machines with:

```
    ss = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
    sc = ss.sparkContext
```

Comment: What does your setup look like? Are you running these commands in a spark-shell that is pointing to your cluster with the `--master` configuration? Are you running these on a k8s cluster? Are you running these commands on your local laptop? Please edit your question to add these bits of information :)

Comment: updated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a version from 3.0 onwards you can use the sql function [version](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#version) (java example):

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
        .getOrCreate();

spark.sql("select version()").show();
```

yields:

```
+--------------------+
|           version()|
+--------------------+
|3.3.2 5103e00c4ce...|
+--------------------+
```

The python api in version 3.5+ also supports this [version](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.version.html#pyspark.sql.functions.version):

```py
df = spark.range(1)
df.select(version()).show(truncate=False) 
+----------------------------------------------+
|version()                                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
|3.5.0 cafbea5b13623276517a9d716f75745eff91f616|
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: interesting, those commands also give me the pyspark version, but the commit listed there is the commit id from the Spark repo from where I built the pyspark python wheel. However, I haven't deployed that version of the repo to the spark cluster yet, so it is not actually giving me the version from the cluster, only the version from which pyspark was built.

Comment: Alas, the expression is constant folded away on the jvm pyspark server.  if your pyspark server isn't the same spark version as actual spark driver you'll have potential compatibility issues.   that said there isn't any other "delayed" function available, if you can deploy extra jars on both the jvm pyspark server and the cluster you could make a java / scala UDF to get the version via classOf[Expression].getPackage.getSpecificationVersion but this doesn't work on databricks ( and may not on other runtimes )